# Enclosed field key and field value with square brackets when create operation of laravel migration is performed

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have field name key and value in my schema. When i perform migration command it enclose my fields key and value with square brackets in my sql table.The sample of fields created after migration in sql table is given below:

[key]
[value]

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class check extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('api_keys',function(Blueprint $table){

             $table->string('value',255)->comment = "Key Value";
             $table->integer('Level')->nullable()->comment = "Key Level";

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('api_keys');
    }
}
```

I have tried every possible solution but still cannot figured out the reason behind enclosing the fields **"[key]" and "[value]" with square brackets** inside my sql table.

Comment: probably because they are reserved words in SQL, so they are enclosed in brackets, that could depend on the database driver. Can you explain what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Basically "Key" and "value" are ODBC reserved words,square brackets indicates to avoid such kind of naming convention for fields.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017